# how can i manipulate my heading to look like this?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to implement the same style as in the picture as my "Heading 1"
with the numbering being **bold** and a different font on the first line and the section title on the next line followed by a line at the end. How can I do that in word?

[image: Example Heading]

Also, in the Table of Contents, it shows up as normal:

4. Research Methods and Material …….32

Comment: I don't think that would be possible. You probably need to have two separate styles for the heading, and also create / manipulate manually your TOC. Your picture is from a book, as far as I know Word is not the preferred tool for editing entire books.

Comment: I've answered the primary part of the question regarding the chapter header, but I'm unclear as to how you want the TOC to appear.  If you could expand that, it's probably doable.  Also, as Máté noted, Word may not be the best platform for book writing/editing, so you may not be able to get exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I want my toc to read like this:  4.Research methods and materials BUT im having a problem with the TOC not recognizing that the number (4) and text ( Research methods and materials) are the same header and not two separate ones, so now I get  4...…………………….. on the next line Research methods and materials...………...

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to accomplish this, but Máté's comments about using Word to edit a book is worth considering.  Something like this is likely better suited to Latex (but I'm not a Latex user, so no guarantees).

To make a similar header to the one described, you'll need to set-up your Heading and use multi-level numbering.

**Heading** (assuming this is Heading1, change as appropriate)
  1. Modify Heading1.
  2. Format your Heading Font, as desired.
  3. Format your Heading Paragraph, you'll need to adjust spacing, and check `Page Break Before` on the `Line and Page Breaks` tab.  Also, if you want a larger top margin, you can simulate it hear by adjusting the `Spacing` `Before` value (you can enter an inch value like this `2"` and it will automagically convert it to pts for you).
  4. Format your Heading Border, you'll need to add an appropriate sized and colored line to the bottom of the paragraph.

**Multi-level Numbering**
  1. Define a new multi-level list.
  2. Select Level 1 and click the `More` button on the bottom (to expose additional options).
  3. `Link Level to Style` Heading1 (or whatever you formatted above).
  4. `Number Format`: remove any trailing periods or parenthesis (unless you want them).
  5. `Number Alignment`: Right.
  6. `Aligned At`: your right margin value.

**Document**
  1. Type your Chapter Title, start with a `Space` (this is a quirk that is necessary to have your text follow on a second line, after your number, otherwise the first letter will be on the same line as the number) and follow with a paragraph return `Enter`.
  2. Assign Heading1 to your chapter.
  3. Continue typing your chapter content and assign a different style (e.g. Heading2 or Normal) to subsequent paragraphs.

[image]

Comment: I want my toc to read like this: 4.Research methods and materials BUT im having a problem with the TOC not recognizing that the number (4) and text ( Research methods and materials) are the same header and not two separate ones, so now I get 4...…………………….. on the next line Research methods and materials...………...